# Updating ruby version with Rbenv but gems apparently not updated

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I have just updated Ruby from version *1.9.3-p448* to *1.9.3-p484* using `rbenv` on a Ubuntu Production server. The updating seems to be successful. Ruby version shows the latest version I just updated.

However when I look at the gems for this version *1.9.3-p484* under the  directory:
`.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems`.

I only find a few gems in that directory. And when I looked at the directory of the previous version, there is a whole bunch of gems in there. Did I miss a step somewhere in the ruby update process?

Now that I am using the new ruby version, do I need to reinstall all the gems for this version? If so, will running `bundle install` does the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to  run `bundle install` for the active ruby version. Please make sure that the active ruby version, and the gemset for the application are set properly. Just do the following (in *Linux/MacOS*):

```
$ cat .ruby-version
ruby-1.9.3-p484

$ cat .ruby-gemset
your_app_name
```

And before gem update, please re-neter into the your application/gem folder.

```
$ cd ..
$ cd your_app_name
```

I have an additional note. If your application is a *gem*, there is no reason to add the `.ruby-version`, and `.ruby-gemset` files into the *git* repository, just add them into `.gitignore` file. When your application is a *rails* app, adding the files along with the `Gemfile.lock` into *git* repo has make sense, because you fix ruby version, and gem set for web-application to one that are those, which uniquely will work. Also some cloud services like *heroku* requires `Gemfile.lock` to be added into a *git* repo.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes. Since rbenv maintains a separate directory for each ruby installation, you'll need to run `bundle` again to install the gems for that ruby.

When you install a gem running under ruby 1.9.3-p448 for example, that gem will be installed ***only*** for that ruby. When you switch to another version of ruby, that gem will not be available for use until you install it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mentioned that when I switch to another version of ruby, the previous version gems will not be available for use for the new version. However I found it strange that I am using the new version and my app is still working fine even though the gems for the new version has not been installed. And if I do a bundle exec gem list in my application, it shows all the previous gems. Just trying to understand why this is so.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you run `ruby -v` inside your application's directory, what is the output? If you have previously configured rbenv with `rbenv [global|local] <ruby version>`, that version will still be in use in that directory and its sub-directories.

Comment: ruby version is the new version 1.9.3-p484. After installing the new version, I did the rbenv global and rbenv rehash. Which was what puzzled me because I had the new version ruby and not install the gems afresh for this version of ruby, and yet my app is still functioning. Now come to think of it,when I ran bundle exec gem list I believe the gems listed were those in the Gemfile.lock. And if I just run gem list, it will only list what's in the .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484... folder. That probably accounts for why the app is still running without new install of gems.