# Bundle install is using a different Ruby version?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, rbenv

I tried to install Ruby 2.0.0-p353 on Vagrant using knife-solo.
When I logged in as root and vagrant, `ruby -v` returns Ruby 2.0.0-p353.

However, when I run `bundle install` in a Rails project, the following statement is displayed:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

The default version of Ruby is 1.8.7, so I think `bundle install` is referring to this.
What should I do to solve this problem?

```
$ cat site-cookbooks/ruby/recipes/default.rb

group 'rbenv' do
  action :create
  members 'vagrant'
  append true
end

git '/usr/local/rbenv' do
  repository 'git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git'
  reference 'master'
  action :checkout
  user "#{node.user}"
  group 'rbenv'
end

directory '/usr/local/rbenv/plugins' do
  owner "#{node.user}"
  group 'rbenv'
  mode 0755
  action :create
end

template '/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh' do
  owner "#{node.user}"
  group "#{node.user}"
  mode 0644
end

git '/usr/local/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build' do
  repository 'git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git'
  reference 'master'
  action :checkout
  user "#{node.user}"
  group 'rbenv'
end

execute 'ruby install' do
  not_if "source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh; rbenv versions | grep #{node.ruby.version}"
  command "source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh; rbenv install #{node.ruby.version}"
  action :run
end

execute 'ruby change' do
  command "source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh; rbenv global #{node.ruby.version}; rbenv rehash"
  action :run
end

$ cat site-cookbooks/ruby/attributes/default.rb

default['user'] = 'root'
default['ruby']['version'] = '2.0.0-p353'

$ cat site-cookbooks/ruby/templates/default/rbenv.sh.rb

export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: it you have used `rbenv`, please try my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531782/updating-ruby-version-with-rbenv-but-gems-apparently-not-updated/20535848#20535848

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to do according to that page, but I couldn't. For example, `bundle install` returns `Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.`.

Comment: But you have ruby version >= 1.9.3, do you have 2.0.0? or 1.8.7?

Comment: `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]`, so I think it should be able to run without problem.

Comment: and `bundle exec ruby -v` what returns?

Comment: and which ruby version is defined in `Gemfile`?

Comment: An error has occurred. `bundle exec ruby -v` returns `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:296:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.0.2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)`. I appreciate your kindness.

Comment: It does not define anything to Gemfile.

Comment: ok, add only `ruby '2.0.0` line into `Gemfile`. remove all gem dependencies from `Gemfile`, and run `bundle exec ruby -v` again? May be it is good idea to go to chat?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. I wrote only `ruby '2.0.0'` to Gemfile. `bundle exec ruby -v` returns `Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0`.

Comment: There is a problem with the rbenv... your bundle thinks thar current ruby version is not 2.0.0... please show output of `rbenv versions`, `rbenv local`, and `rbenv version`

Comment: These all commands return `2.0.0-p353`.

Comment: `which ruby` returns `/usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby` but `cat /usr/bin/bundle` displays `#!/usr/bin/ruby` at first line. Would this be OK?

Comment: ok, just try to install bundler, do `bundle exec gem install bundler` or just `gem install bundler`

Comment: `sudo gem list` returns `bundle`(system default), but `gem list` not returns it. So I think `bundle` can't installed correctly by chef. After execute `gem install bundle`, it worked out. Thank you very much!!

Comment: ok, I'll do the answer

Comment: Now you can remove specific ruby version from `Gemfile`

Comment: Please verify steps in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do the following steps to fix the problem:

1. Make sure that the following commands returns the proper version of ruby:

   ```
   $ rbenv versions
     system
     2.0.0-p353

   $ rbenv local
   ruby-2.0.0

   $ rbenv version
     2.0.0-p353
   ```
2. Make sure that getting the version of ruby is correct:

   ```
   $ bundle exec ruby -v
   ruby 2.0.0-p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
   ```
3. If you got invalid version of ruby, you shell to verify that problem is in `bundler` by calling:

   ```
   $ bundle exec ruby -v
   ruby 1.8.7

   $ which bundle
   /usr/bin/bundle
   ```

   It says that it will call system ruby to proceed ruby scripts.
4. Reinstall bundler, and then make sure that now current ruby is valid:

   ```
   $ gem install bundler

   $ bundle exec ruby -v
   ruby 2.0.0-p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
   ```

Also refer to how to properly set up a ruby project, which is being developed under rbenv/rvm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531782/updating-ruby-version-with-rbenv-but-gems-apparently-not-updated/20535848#20535848):